# SQL inner join based on table name pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

On this legacy SQL Database with hundreds of tables, I need to do a inner join on all tables whose name follows a format:

- `barX_foo_bazX`
- `barX_foo_bazY`
- `barZ_foo_bazZ`
- I would like to inner join all tables with foo in their name

I am not sure this is possible at all.

Clearly, with this syntax it is not (but it may help understand what I'm aiming at):

```
USE [LegacyDB_Name]

SELECT *
FROM '%_foo_%' inner join '%_foo_%'
where my_stuff_is(some condition)
```

Any Suggestions? Ideas on how I can do this? Maybe there is an easier path this young padawan is not seeing...

Many Thanks!

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: @vetras :if you can come up with join conditions for each table or if they are same,then it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure this is possible at all.

Nope, table names cannot contain or use wildcards, they must be strings.

My advice would be to find whatever program makes these select queries and include whatever pattern matching you need in the queries in there.

But your finished query must contain table names as strings.

Comment: Just a thought, what if you select table names from the schema using a `with` statement and processing that before executing the query in a function so that you have an array of strings that have been filtered beforehand?

Comment: @Tikkes Thats what I mean by "Including what ever pattern matching you need in the program that creates the queries". Use some other info to fetch the names and then make the queries, but the queries must contain proper table names.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the simplest way to do this is to declare a cursor based on the below query and build a dynamic sql query.  Research tsql cursor and dynamic sql execution and it should be fairly simple.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM information_schema.tables
    Where Table_Type = 'Base Table' And Table_Name Like '%_foo_%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your tables all have the same structure (i.e. columns), then you could do this in two steps.

1. Generate the SQL statement:

   ```
   select 'UNION ALL SELECT ''' + table_name + ''' AS table_name, * FROM ' 
          + table_name AS stmt
   from   information_schema.tables
   where  table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
      and table_catalog = 'LegacyDB_Name'
      and table_name LIKE '%foo%';
   ```

   The output will be something like:

   ```
   stmt
   --------------------------------------------------------------------
   UNION ALL SELECT 'barX_foo_bazX' AS table_name, * FROM barX_foo_bazX
   UNION ALL SELECT 'barX_foo_bazY' AS table_name, * FROM barX_foo_bazY
   UNION ALL SELECT 'barX_foo_bazZ' AS table_name, * FROM barX_foo_bazZ
   ```

   From this output, copy the SQL rows and remove the first 2 words (`UNION ALL`) from the first line. This is a valid SQL statement.
2. Execute the SQL statement derived above

   If you need this SQL more often, then create a view for it:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_foo AS
                 SELECT 'barX_foo_bazX' AS table_name, * FROM barX_foo_bazX
       UNION ALL SELECT 'barX_foo_bazY' AS table_name, * FROM barX_foo_bazY
       UNION ALL SELECT 'barX_foo_bazZ' AS table_name, * FROM barX_foo_bazZ;
   ```

   Now you can query like

   ```
   SELECT * FROM all_foo WHERE ...
   ```